# Why don't we have a bot to check broken links?

Tags: discussion

As most of us know, a link may be broken in the following ways:

- DNS ERROR
- HOST NOT FOUND
- CONNECTION REFUSED
- HTTP NOT FOUND (404)
- CONTENT CHANGED

The first four are easy and cheep to check, the last one is more complicated and expensive.
I don't find broken links often, but such checks could be healthy, thinking in future time.

BTW: Maybe these little icons (`a[noflow]:after`) indicating the link health.

Comment: as a dictator, i want suspend user related reputation until the post is fixed. then refund.

Comment: This is exactly why link-only answers are bad and you are supposed to pull the relevant info from your linked resource into your post. If you do that, and do it right, then you don't have to worry about link-rot affecting your post.

Comment: "i want suspend user related reputation until the post is fixed. then refund" - That'd be way too harsh for otherwise detailed answers that happen to have a link in them to a supplementary resource which has gone down.

Comment: Just because a link is bad right now doesn't mean it always will be.  And many links remain useful even if they go permanently dead, as they indicate that the information *has* existed (and probably still does for those who care to look).  Some by their very file and site names, provide useful paths for investigation.  In short, links may not be ideal answers, but they still tend to be great resources.

Comment: @Chris, *and many links remain useful even if they go permanently dead, as they indicate that the information has existed (and probably still does for those who care to look)*. Nope, it doesn't work that way. Otherwise I would be able to throw a picture of the Rosetta Stone as an answer practically everywhere.

Comment: Not all links of course, but the fact of the matter is that most resources exist in more than one place on the net, so if you know what something is called, you are far ahead dropping that into a search engine, as compared to starting from scratch.  And the site hosting the original topic may still be around offering updated resources under a different organizational scheme.  Try it sometime - I've found that for a resource that seems like it was worth something to begin with, I can almost always quickly re-locate it.

Answer (score 11):

There are currently **8,352,372 questions** on Stack Overflow. Most of them contain links, and quite a few of them contain *several* links.

Among these questions, **2,127,436** are deemed "unanswered", which makes **6,224,936 questions with one or more worthy answers**, most of these containing links, and so on and so forth.

Hitting all of those links, even once in a while, only to verify their validity cannot possibly scale. You will spend your main bandwidth just to prevent link rot, and you will generate enough traffic for sysadms around the world to routinely throw rocks at you in the street.

Until better times where TCP packets are free, handling link rot should be the responsibility of the original poster first, the community second, not of the system.

Comment: Not that I disagree with what you've said but 6.2m checks per day is easy, given scale - 300 VMs can do far more than most people think..

Comment: @Ben, the problem is not 6.2M checks. The problem is 8.4M checks (multiplied by several links) multiplied by (a few answers per question multiplied by several links). When you're done handling that, you're not running a Q/A site anymore.

Comment: No, definitely not a QA site - but you're also doing a lot less work than a proper scraper; assuming a hit per second and 2 links per post you'd only need 7 cores to cycle through them all (6.8m links) monthly. It's not necessarily what SE should be getting into but hundreds of millions a month is now the norm and it's not that difficult. It might even be necessary given the mess Oracle have just made of their documentation :-(.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Your "multiplied by several links" sounds distinctly dubious to me. I strongly suspect that the *average* number of links per post is less than one. While there are certainly several answers with multiple links, there are also an awful lot with none at all. It sounds perfectly feasible to me - I'm not sure that "suspending rep" is the answer, but giving users information about which of their answers have broken links feels like a reasonable idea to me.

Comment: (Although I've just realized that the 8.4M isn't total posts... it would be interesting to start with *that* number rather than trying to guess based solely on the number of questions.)

Comment: @JonSkeet searching for `Url:"*"` brings back [6,040,760](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Url%3A%22*%22) results which I think is the number of posts of both types containing at least one URL. My guess is that the number of distinct URLs might be quite a lot lower though. Often the same pages get linked to repeatedly.

Comment: Right. That definitely doesn't sound like too many to crawl once per month, for example (just performing HEAD requests).

Comment: Wikimedia has link rot detection on some of their voluminous sites, and they are still alive. Their number of external links is probably similar to ours or higher. Dead link get a red indicator, that makes it easy for passing-by contributors to notice and fix them.

Answer (score 11):

We have bots to check broken links. We're the bots. If you spot a broken link:

- Find the updated version if it moved, update the link in the answer.
- Consider finding the page on http://archive.org and linking to an archived version instead.
- Leave a comment.
- If the answer is a [link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) consider a flag, or a down-vote if you find the answer unhelpful.

You will be assimilated. BEEP BOOP

Answer (score -2):

It makes no sense to have an automatic procedure to indicate a broken link. There are already community-enforced practices in place to deal with link rot, including removing the link, updating the link or moving the relevant information from the link into the question or answer. It offers no practical benefit for the disproportionate amount of server strain that would follow. In the case that a link is found to be broken, then somebody could edit "link is broken as of this date" into the answer, or as a comment, which takes substantially less resources.